# Force Richtextbox to redraw only its foreground

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

do you know how to force a Richtextbox to redraw ONLY it's foreground (not background).

Should i send a message or something like that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `OnPaintBackground` method.

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    if (_I_need_to_paint_background) {
        base.OnPaintBackground(pevent)
    }
}
```

Of cause this means that you have to derive your own RichTextBox form the original

```
public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    ...

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // Your background painting logic goes here
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your foreground painting logic goes here
    }
}
```

With the `Invalidate` method of controls you can tell controls that they should redraw themselves. The `Refresh` method invalidates a control and tells it to redraw itself immediately (using `OnPaintBackground` and `OnPaint`).

Comment: the problem is that i want do draw the Background and then force to draw the Foreground once again on top of it...

Comment: You can implement your own background drawing logic in `OnPaintBackground` or, alernatively, disable it as shown above and draw it in `OnPaint`. Then your foreground drawing logic goes to `OnPaint`. Always do all your painting there. You can call `Invalidate` to trigger redrawing.